# Como usar 2 versiones de ajax sin conflicto

Tags: php, ajax

Aquí pueden ver la pagina y el error que arroja

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>

  <!--Icono Titulo-->

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Logo.ico"/>

  <title>PAUL MEDINA DESIGNER</title>

  <!--Codigo Paginas-->

  <link href="Css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <link href="Css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <link href="Css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <link href="Js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/avascript"/>

  <link href="Js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/avascript"/>

  <link href="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/avascript"/>

    <!--Codigo Menu-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!--Banner--> 

  <link href="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/allinone_carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script src="Js/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/allinone_carousel.js"></script>

  <script src="Js/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>

  <script src="Js/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/BannerMovimiento.js"></script>

  <!--Codigo Personalizado-->

  <link href="Css/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/allinone_carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <link href="Css/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <!--Letra-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"/>

 </head>

 <header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark menuCSS3">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/Logo.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;"><br>Paúl Medina Designer</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 menuCSS3">

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">TRAYECTORIA</a></li>

       <li class="nav-item dropdown">

          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="color: white;" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CEREMONIAS</a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="background-color: #343a40;">

            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color: white;" href="#">NOVIAS</a>

            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color: white;" href="#">15 AÑOS</a>

            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color: white;" href="#">SOCIALES</a>

          </div>

        </li>

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">EVENTOS</a></li>

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">MODA ARTESANAL</a></li>

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">RECONOCIMIENTOS</a></li>

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">CONTACTANOS</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </nav>

  </header>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row flex-xl-nowrap">

      <body class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">

        <!--Pagina-->

        <main class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">

     <center><FONT class="Titulo3">Paúl Medina <br>Designer</FONT></center>

     <!--Banner-->

     <div class="banner" id="bannerBg">

      <div id="containingDiv">

       <div id="allinone_carousel_charming">

        <div class="myloader"></div>

        <ul class="allinone_carousel_list">

         <li><img title="1" src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/vestido-casual-juvenil-elegante-manga-larga-formal-237-D_NQ_NP_614069-MLM27319998265_052018-F.jpg" alt="" /></li>

         <li><img title="2" src="http://eslamoda.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/05/vestido-graduacion-featured.jpg" alt="" /></li>

         <li><img title="3" src="https://mx.hola.com/imagenes/novias/2017091899443/vestidos-fiesta-invitada-boda-tarde-hk/0-487-821/vestidos-boda-noche1-m.jpg" alt="" /></li>

         <li><img title="4" src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/7e/3c/dc/7e3cdce33acfcca07aad611759b98f20.jpg" alt="" /></li>

        </ul>

       </div>

      </div>

      <div id="bottomText">

       <img src="" alt="">

      </div>

     </div>

    </main>

   </body>

  </div>

 </div> 

</html>
```

Este es el error que me arroja y se cicla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me encontré este código pero no se como utilizarlo

```html
<!-- load jQuery 1.9.0 -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_9_0 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
 
<!-- load jQuery 3.3.1 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
var jQuery_3_3_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Lo solucione de esta forma

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <!--Icono Titulo-->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Logo.ico"/>
  <title>PAUL MEDINA DESIGNER</title>
  <!--Codigo Paginas-->
  <link href="Css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="Css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="Css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="Js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/avascript"/>
  <link href="Js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/avascript"/>
  <link href="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/avascript"/>
    <!--Codigo Menu-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--Codigo Personalizado-->
  <link href="Css/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!--Banner-->
  <link href="Css/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/allinone_carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="Js/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/allinone_carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/BannerMovimiento.js"></script>
  <!--Letra-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"/>
 </head>
  <header>
    <!--Menu-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark menuCSS3">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Imagenes/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/Logo.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;"><br>Paúl Medina Designer</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 menuCSS3">

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">TRAYECTORIA</a></li>

       <li class="nav-item dropdown">

          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="color: white;" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CEREMONIAS</a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="background-color: #343a40;">

            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color: white;" href="#">NOVIAS</a>

            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color: white;" href="#">15 AÑOS</a>

            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color: white;" href="#">SOCIALES</a>

          </div>

        </li>

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">EVENTOS</a></li>

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">MODA ARTESANAL</a></li>

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">RECONOCIMIENTOS</a></li>

       <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" style="color: white;" href="#">CONTACTANOS</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </nav>
  </header>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-xl-nowrap">
   <body class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
        <!--Pagina-->
        <main class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
     <center><FONT class="Titulo3">Paúl Medina <br>Designer</FONT>
     <!--Banner-->
     <div class="banner" id="bannerBg" >
      <div id="containingDiv">
       <div id="allinone_carousel_charming" >
        <div class="myloader"></div>
        <ul class="allinone_carousel_list">
         <?php 
          require 'Conexion.php';
          $sql = "SELECT `Nombre_Imagen` FROM `vestido` WHERE `Pagina_Web_ID` = 911;";
          $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)or die ("ERROR DE ENVIO");
          while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
          echo '<li><img src="Imagenes/PAUL_MEDINA_DESIGNER/'.$fila[0].'" alt="" /></li>';
          }
         ?>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div></center>
    </main>
   </body>
  </div>
 </div> 
</html>
```

Comment: Y ¿por qué usar dos versiones de jQuery, siendo además las dos tan antiguas? Una es de 2013 y otra de 2014. Deberías eliminar las dos y usar una versión más moderna

Comment: Lo mismo me pregunto yo, @PabloLozano, a no ser que quiera seguir manteniendo cierto código obsoleto porque todavía no haya podido actualizarlo o algo así.

Comment: es que ocupo usar 2 versiones y son script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Pablo Lozano
No tengo mucha experiencia en algunos aspectos de edición web, se podría decir que soy nuevo, pero quiero usar estas 2 versiones de ajax para que me funcione un menú desplegable y un banner en 3d, ya le intente solo dejar uno pero ya tiene código preestablecido y si dejo solo uno me desaparece el banner o no funciona el despliegue del menú como podría solucionarlo

Comment: @9999emmy9999 Las dos versiones de jQuery hacen básicamente lo mismo y tener dos (sin necesidad de soportar versiones antiguas) es innecesario y puede tener efectos negativos. El error que recibes no está relacionado con el código compartido y puede ser porque estás intentando usar alguna funcionalidad de jQueryUI sin incorporar jQueryUI a tu proyecto. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para que podamos ver el error en la publicación directamente.

Comment: @A. Cedano no se como actualizar el código que es usado de los ajax que se son las versiones 1.9.0 y 3.3.1 los códigos utilizados están en la parte de arriba y me manda un error ciclado como se ve en la imagen de color rojo que es la versión 3.3.1 y los 2 ajax a lo que e visto solo sirven para en movimiento del banner y del menú como podría utilizar los ajax para que no causen conflicto y de aquí saque el código para separar los ajax https://www.jabenitez.com/2016/06/13/utilizar-distintas-versiones-de-jquery-en-una-misma-web/ y no se como aplicarlo

Comment: El problema no es tanto de las librerías, con que dejes una sola o pongas la version 3 directamente no daría problema. Los errores que se ven es porque tu domino es `https` y para incluir la librería estás usando `http`, eso crea todos los errores `Mixed content` que te muestra. Debes usar en todo `https`. Luego muestra varios errores `404`, eso es contenido que no encuentra, debes revisar esas URL.

Comment: Puedes usar esta versión de jQuery: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` y quitar las antiguas, y si usas otras librerías adicionales, busca la más reciente ([ver aquí](https://code.jquery.com)) y ponla también usando siempre `https`.

Comment: @A. Cedano gracias, ya pude arreglarlo deje solo un jQuery 3.3.1 y descargue todos los datos del slider, js, css y porque cuando agarraba los datos de el sitio web hacia conflictos y por eso lo tuve que hacer local y con un solo ajax.